# PRECISO DE AJUDA PARA ORDENAR UMA CONSULTA

Tags: sql, query, order-by

Estou fazendo uma consulta em que estou retornando o último registro do dia(que no caso tem os dias porém existem vários registros de hora em um dia, e estou pegando o ultimo deles em um sub select), o problema é que não consigo ordenar no final, ele fica embaralhado, já tentei order by e não dá certo. Segue a query:

**OBS: Quero ordenar a coluna 'CreatedOn'**

```
    SELECT
  rl.WipOrderNo,
  CAST(rl.CreatedOn AS smalldatetime) AS CreatedOn,
  rl.RegularHours
FROM resource_labor rl

WHERE CAST(rl.CreatedOn AS date) = CAST(rl.CreatedOn AS date)
AND rl.WipOrderNo = rl.WipOrderNo

GROUP BY CAST(rl.CreatedOn AS smalldatetime),
         rl.WipOrderNo,
         rl.RegularHours
```

[image: Resultado da QUERY]

Comment: vc quer ordenar pelo que?

Comment: ordenar a coluna CreatedOn em crescente

Comment: qual o tipo do campo?

Comment: datetime, é em sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você possa fazer algo tipo:

```
  GROUP BY  CONVERT(date, CreatedOn) , 
           rl.WipOrderNo,
           rl.RegularHours

   ORDER BY  CONVERT(date, CreatedOn) desc
```

Comment: deu o seguinte erro: Mensagem 8120, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 19
Column 'resource_labor.CreatedOn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.


Deu erro na 3ª linha da query

Comment: é possivel que quando vc agrupa por data, para uma mesma data existam diferentes WipOrderNo, por exemplo. Dessa maneira, o select nao entende qual deles mostrar.

Comment: olha esse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e
A primeira resposta explica direito esse tipo de erro.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema! Muito obrigado, ajudou muito com aquele convert do group by e do order by, e com o post indicado! Valeu